# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4 and __GSHandlerCheck_EH4

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to build a library and link it to an app. Library build is fine, but linking to the app throws these errors:

> clipper.lib(clipper.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4

> clipper.lib(clipper.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4

#### Cause

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65672356/3405291) and [that](https://github.com/google/filament/issues/2142#issuecomment-588870445), the errors might be due to building the lib with VS **2019** toolset, but the app is using VS **2017** toolset.

---

#### Tried

I'm building the library with these commands:

```
cd lib/src/clipper
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Debug
cmake --build . --config Release
```

Even on VS 2017 Command Prompt, CMake builds the lib for VS 2019:

[image: CMake log screenshot]

#### Question

What is the easiest/fastest way to force CMake to build for VS 2017 rather than 2019?

Comment: Just pass proper [CMake generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) to cmake: `-G"Visual Studio 15 2017"`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Your suggestion resolved the errors by replacing `cmake ..` with `cmake  -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @Tsyvarev , the errors got resolved by replacing

```
cmake ..
```

with:

```
cmake  -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but where do I add -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" in the project settings? 
I am not calling cmake directly but Visual Studio is when I build a project or solution. So, I have not been able to successfully find a way to pass this parameter.

Comment: @DavidBowser I'm not sure :( I just use `cmake` command. I didn't use the Visual Studio. But I think you ask a new question about it :)